# SQL query to handle the grouping - SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, group-by, ssrs-2012

My sql query

```
SELECT SEX, col1, col2, col3, A1, A2 FROM Table1
```

result like this

[image]

how to write query to get result like below

[image]

Actually, I have to generate a result like this in SSRS Table. You can also advise handling this case in SSRS result to print list above.

Comment: We seem to have a lot of solutions when the question is not even clear. What is the criteria for blank cells? Is it when the values are duplicated from the row above?, if so are the rows always going to be in this order? Is it just when the Sex is Male?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Declare @table  Table 
    (
      SEX nvarchar(max), 
      col1 int, 
      col2 int, 
      col3 int, 
      A1 int, 
      A2 int 
    )

INSERT into @table (SEX, col1, col2, col3,A1,A2)
values 
    ('Female', '0', '0', '0','27','83'),
    ('Male', '1', '0', '8','27','83'),
    ('Female', '0', '0', '0','6','3'),
    ('Male', '0', '0', '1','6','3')

  Select 
  SEX, col1, col2, col3,
  case  when col3=('8') or col3=('1')  then null else A1 end [A1],
  case  when col3=('8') or col3=('1')then null else A2 end [A2]
  From @table 

SEX    |col1 |col2 |col3 |A1   |A2
-----------------------------------
Female |0    |0    |0    |27   |83
Male   |1    |0    |8    |NULL |NULL
Female |0    |0    |0    |6    |3
Male   |0    |0    |1    |NULL |NULL
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` function to check the duplicate value & replace with `null`

```
SELECT SEX, col1, col2, col3, 
       case when row_number() over (partition by A1 order by SEX) > 1 then null else A1 end A1,
       case when row_number() over (partition by A2 order by SEX) > 1 then null else A2 end A2 
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with `IIF`. Query based on that you want to keep values of `A1 and A2` where `col1, col2, col3` are 0, otherwise set blank

```
SELECT 
    SEX, col1, col2, col3
    , A1 = iif(col1 + col2 + col3 = 0, cast(A1 as varchar(20)), '')
    , A2 = iif(col1 + col2 + col3 = 0, cast(A2 as varchar(20)), '')
FROM 
    Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer depends on one Id column to differentiate between all records. I am using LAG SQL function to achieve the desired output :

```
declare @table1 table (
    id int identity(1,1),
    sex varchar(10),
    col1 int,
    col2 int,
    col3 int,
    A1 int,
    A2 int
)

insert into @table1 (sex, col1, col2, col3, A1, A2)
select 'Female',0,0,0,27,83 union all
select 'Male',1,0,8,27,83 union all
select 'Female',0,0,0,6,3 union all
select 'Male',0,0,1,6,3

select sex,col1,col2,col3,
    A1 = (case when lag(A1,1,0) over (order by id) = A1 then null else A1 end),
    A2 = (case when lag(A2,1,0) over (order by id) = A2 then null else A2 end)
from @Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

These are all very complicated solutions. You just need to set the `HideDuplicates` property (under other) on the field in the report to the name of the dataset